# Изменение метода для unit теста

Tags: c#

Был следующий метод

```
public void SumOfNumbers()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите слагаемые через запятую!"); 

    int[] arr =
        Console.ReadLine()
            .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(i => int.Parse(i))
            .ToArray<int>();

    Console.WriteLine("Сумма слагаемых: {0}", arr[0] + arr[1])
}
```

Потребовалось написать тест под него, поэтому переделал в

```
public int Summ(string str)
{
    return str.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(i => int.Parse(i)).Sum();
}
```

Теперь нужно вычислять сумму не всех элементов, а только конкретных(как в первом методе). Вопрос, как это реализовать?

Comment: Метод должен называться Sum, а не Summ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно сложить только первые два числа. Тогда воспользуйтесь методом `Take()`:

```
public int Summ(string str)
{
    return str.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Take(2)
        .Select(i => int.Parse(i))
        .Sum();
}
```

Этот же метод вы могли использовать и в оригинальном методе `SumOfNumbers`, чтобы преобразовать в массив только первые два элемента.

Comment: Спасибо за оперативной ответ. На самом деле в теле первого метода была строка Console.WriteLine("Сумма слагаемых: {0}", arr[0] + arr[1]); Переделывал потому что под него невозможно было написать тест.

Comment: @cruim да, я понимаю. Я имел в виду, что при формировании `int[] arr` вы могли бы сразу оставлять в массиве только два элемента. Если ответ помог, можете отметить его как верный (галочка слева от ответа).